# apex:inputField

Tags: visualforce, cross-domain

I created a Visualforce page whose source code is:

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="PopupController" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" title="Request to Change">
<apex:includeScript value="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" />
<apex:form id="form">
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
<apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!save}" onclick="callParent(this);" id="submit" rerender="form"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Cancel" id="cancel"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
  <apex:outputField label="Lead :" value="{!Lead.Name}"/>
  <apex:inputField label="Assign To Partner :" value="{! req.PartnerUserId__c}" />
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  document.domain = document.domain;
  function callParent(){
    console.log('coming here');
    parent.postMessage('closeModal','*');   
    return true;
  }

  </script>
  <apex:outputText value="Your request successfully submitted" rendered="{! req.Id != null}"/>
</apex:page>
```

Here is one lookup field I created it as a iframe in a modal not a new window page popup. When I try to click on field it opens a window and showing correct user name but when I click on any user's name it doesn't close window. Nothing happens no assignment. PartnerUserId__c is a lookup to User sobject. Please help why I am having such issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: I see you're using jQuery. I don't see an `OnClick` in your code or a `BlurAway`, the latter being what you'd use to close it if you clicked away. Perhaps you need something along those lines? Might want to check the event handlers on the jQuery site for all the possible options available for use.

Comment: i got the solution right now busy a lot will write answer here by tomorrow.Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I open your page directly, click on the lookup icon, then use "View" -> "Developer" -> "Developer Tools" and then select the name in the lookup dialog I see this error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "https://cvx.na15.visual.force.com" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "https://cvx.na15.visual.force.com". The frame being accessed set
>   "document.domain" to "cvx.na15.visual.force.com", but the frame
>   requesting access did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same
>   value to allow access.

presumably because of your:

```
document.domain = document.domain;
```

line. Removing that stops the problem from happening the way I opened the page.

Presumably your code does not work with that line removed either?

You should post the page that you open your posted page from; if that is also Visualforce then you should not have a cross-domain problem.